# Compute matrix-vector multiplication without having the matrix.

Tags: matrices, vectors, finite-element-method

So I am trying to think of a way to make a Matrix-Vector multiplication. What I have is a global stiffness matrix of 1D element with linear shape functions

$\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{1}{3} & \dfrac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 \\
\dfrac{1}{6} & \dfrac{2}{3} & \dfrac{1}{6} &  0 \\
0 & \dfrac{1}{6} & \dfrac{2}{3} &  \dfrac{1}{6} \\
0 & 0 & \dfrac{1}{6} &  \dfrac{1}{3} \\
\end{bmatrix}$

What I mean is, say I have a vector $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 \end{bmatrix}^{T}$. And I don't want to create extra memory in my computational implementation. Hence I want to recycle the memory that has been allocated to the original vector again.

My instinct is that there should be a way out for this, like how computer scientist (which I am not!) has shows how to swap x and y without using an extra variable by:

```
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

Anyone has any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you take first row and multiply out your vector with? What is the problem in doing that? In some sense to do the multiplication, you must have data and instead of having entire matrix, read the matrix row by row.

Comment: The matrix won't be stored, that's what the problem is. And also, when you do matrix vector multiplication, you need to make calculation based on the *original* value of the vector, not the updated one of the new vector.

Comment: The problem is I am trying to compute y *without* generating extra computational memory for y, and my matrix A is *virtually* there but not there, as it would be replaced by bunch of mathematic algebra as you can see in the brief example I have quoted.

Comment: Are you sure that you can't keep an extra copy of $ x $ in memory as you perform the multiplication?  How large is $ x $?

Comment: @littleO. What OP is saying is that he/she don't want to create extra memory to store the results.

Comment: strictly speaking, yes I can. But this is a scale-able project, so I am trying to *not* store another copy of x for memory efficiency.

Comment: What you want at the end? product of the matrix and vector (say, y) or x and the y?

Comment: Just the result of y = Ax, and y is what I want.

Comment: @QuangThinhHa I have added an answer that uses two index variables and two variables for the moving 3-window, otherwise $x$ gets replaced step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just writing a function that multiplies a vector by this matrix using a for loop?  You can overwrite $x$ as the multiplication is performed, something like this:

```
for i = 2,3,...
   aNext = x[i]
   x[i] = (1/6)a + (2/3)x[i] + (1/6)x[i+1]
   a = aNext
end
```

After the loop, the variable $x$ will store the result of the matrix-vector product.

You could also note that you are performing a convolution, which can be computed very efficiently using the Fast Fourier Transform (if you are careful to handle the boundary correctly). But since your convolution kernel is so small, this might not be faster than just using a for loop.  And the FFT approach might not conserve memory as much as you want.  Although, I just googled and learned that "in place" FFT algorithms have been developed which aim to conserve memory.

Comment: The kernel of the matrix may change as I progress further into my project. But at the moment, can you explain more what you mean by "multiplies a vector by this matrix using a for loop"? Perhaps a pseudocode would help?

Comment: same thing will apply as I said above. In multiplying a matrix by vector in for loop, read the elements in the matrix in a for loop and store the results.

Comment: That problem is avoided using the variable $a$, which temporarily stores the value of the component of $x$ which has just been overwritten.  The updated value of $x[i-1]$ is not used when computing $x[i]$.

Comment: your method will use the updated value of the previous index i in the vector x. I don't think that would return the correct result of the matrix-vector multiplication...

Comment: Ah I see. I will try and will get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assumed problem: Given the setting
\begin{align}
A = \text{tridiag}(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} & \\
a \in \mathbb{R}^n & \quad \text{(main diagonal)} \\ 
b, c \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1} & \quad \text{(upper and lower side diagonal)} \\
x \in \mathbb{R}^n &
\end{align}
you want to calculate $y = Ax$ in a way that $y$ replaces $x$ in memory.

We have
\begin{align}
y_1 &= a_1 \, x_1 + b_1 \, x_2 \\
y_n &= c_{n-1} \, x_{n-1} + a_n x_n \\
y_i &= c_{i-1} \, x_{i-1} + a_i \, x_i + b_i \, x_{i+1}
\quad (i \in \{ 2, \ldots, n-1 \})
\end{align}

Without memory optimization we could try this:

- have indices $(i_-, i, i_+)$, initialize with $(1,2,3)$
- $y_1 = a_1 \, x_1$
- $y_2 = c_1 \, x_1$
- do loop

  - $y_{i_-} = y_{i_-} + b_{i_-} \, x_i$
  - $y_i = y_i + a_i \, x_i$
  - $y_{i_+} = y_{i_+} + c_i \, x_i$
  - $i_- = i$, $i = i_+$, $i_+ = i_+ + 1$
- until $i_+ > n$
- $y_{i_-} = b_{n-1} \, x_n$
- $y_i = a_n \, x_n$

We walk through the matrix from the left to the right, using $x_i$ to contribute to the accumulating sums for the $y$.

After each step we can abandon one $x_i$ and use it to store $y_i$:

- have indices $(i_-, i)$, initialize with $(1,2)$
- have a window $(y, y_+)$, initialize with
- $y = a_1 \, x_1$
- $y_+ = c_1 \, x_1$
- do loop

  - $x_{i_-} = y + b_{i_-} \, x_i$
  - $y = y_+ + a_i \, x_i$
  - $y_+ = c_i \, x_i$
  - $i_- = i$, $i = i + 1$
- until $i >= n$
- $x_{n-1} = y + b_{n-1} \, x_n$
- $x_n = y_+ + a_n \, x_n$

I have not tested this, so there might be bugs. But I hope the idea is clear.

Comment: This approach looks more technically appropriate. How would you expand it to more dense matrix? I.e. incase the diagonal becomes wider?

Comment: If each column would have up to $k$ non-zero entries, one could reuse still only one of the variables in $x$ but would need $k-1$ variables to accumulate the sums. This way the copy of $y$ is still there but it is reduced to $k-1$ in size instead of $n$.